# Retrieving text position (as px/in/cm coordinates) in a Word document

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, doc

I'm using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) to search Word files (doc and docx) to find specified paragraphs and tables. Using various Q/A's from SO and the API, so far this works fine.

What I'd like to do next is to convert the Word file into an image and highlight my search results by drawing boxes around my found paragraphs/tables.

I already wrote the parts, where I draw boxes around text on a PDF and convert those to images (using [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)), and I read that [Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) will be able to print my Word doc to a PDF.

But I'm totally clueless as how to retrieve the position of my text paragraphs/tables. I've searched the API, but the closest I was able to find was the character position in a paragraph (as in the "i-th character in the paragraph"), which tells me nothing right now about where I'm supposed to start/stop drawing my box.

My "Plan-B" would be to "empty print" all the paragraphs I'm not interested in and only "visibly print" my found part into a PDF and retrieve the coordinates there. But I'd really like to avoid that, since I'm afraid there will be other complications to retrieve the exact position if I change the text appearances.

I don't want to draw the box (or otherwise highlight) the text directly in the word doc, since I'm planning to port the presentation part to a web application (and draw the boxes with `<div>` or something).

Does anyone have an idea how I can proceed on this or know some place I might find a hint or solution?

Comment: You need a Word file rendering engine. Apache POI is a file format library, not a rendering library. Try OpenOffice / LibreOffice, they have the ability to fairly accurately render a word document

Comment: I installed OpenOffice to convert DOC to PDF. It doesn't exactly look the same, but that's not of high priority.
Nonetheless, it doesn't help me retrieving the coordinates from the DOC-file. I'm trying parallel search in DOC and PDF file now...